'Extension' and 'setup' functions of the 'numpy.distutils.core' numpy submodules: What functions to use now after deprecation?
I would like to use some 'old' python package where the compilation of the Fortran code is defined in the 'setup.py' file. The compilation in 'setup.py' file is defined with the 'setup' and 'Extension' functions from 'numpy.distutils.core' submodule. Unfortunatelly, the 'numpy.distutils' submodule is deprecated now. Could you, please, tell which python package and functions can be used for compilation of the fortran code instead of 'setup' and 'Extension'?
I was trying to find the solution with the 'meson' package, but, unfortunatelly, was not able to find a ready solution.
